# I cannot resolve the error that model.safetensor is not found in execution of my code?

Tags: python, transformer-model, stable-diffusion, image-generation, safe-tensors

I can not resolve an error in my code that is to generate an image via text and it keeps on giving an error that model.safetensor not found or unet\diffusion_pytorch_model.safetensors not found and I've tried to download those files and tried to put it in several directries where it could use it but then also it is not executable.

```
 from auth_token import auth_token
    from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
    from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
    import torch
    from torch import autocast
    from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
    from io import BytesIO
    import base64 
    
    
    app = FastAPI()
    
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware, 
        allow_credentials=True, 
        allow_origins=["*"], 
        allow_methods=["*"], 
        allow_headers=["*"]
    )
    
    device = "cuda"
    model_id = "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4"
    pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, revision="fp16", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_auth_token=auth_token)
    pipe.to(device)
    
    @app.get("/")
    def generate(prompt: str): 
        with autocast(device): 
            image = pipe(prompt, guidance_scale=8.5).images[0]
    
        image.save("testimage.png")
        buffer = BytesIO()
        image.save(buffer, format="PNG")
        imgstr = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
    
        return Response(content=imgstr, media_type="image/png")
```